# Cannot get simple beginners app to work on tablet using the latest version of Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, tablet

I am new to unity 2021.2.10f and I have become stuck on getting a simple app working on a tablet /real hardware.
I am using unity 2021.2.10f my project is simply the built in
"3D Sample Scene(URP)" I did not change anything to it except added an icon to it (so I can see it in the tablet menu  when it is installed on the android tablet)- the unity project can easily be
recreated-I could not upload it since it the project was large (more than 350MB) for my internet connection.

This is how the  the unity project looks on my computer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFDAx.jpg)

When I compile this to an android apk I just get a pink/magenta screen (as shown below).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6R3y.png)

I also get the message below from the tablet.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kD7d9.png)

After googling around for an answer I found out
this pink/magenta screen means it is a shader problem.After more googling for an answer it was recommended to tick or untick to reset the
~"Auto Graphic API" as a fix-but this did not work for me.
I also changed the color space from Gamma to linear-and again this did not work for me. My tablet is a Maitai MT107.

So my question is -how do I get this to work?
In previous years and using  older versions of unity I have been able to get unity made apps to work perfectly on several different tablets (though not an MT-107).

Also the compiled version of this project does not
work in latest version of Bluestacks on Windows 10-it shows a blank black screen instead of a pink screen-may be it is related to that-
maybe if I can get it to work with the Bluestacks emulator it will work on real hardware-but I do not know what exactly the problem is that is stopping the app working on the MT107.

Comment: @Confused as opposed to unity Unreal Engine where you must program in c/c++

Comment: @shingo  how?-there is no option I can see to select OpenGLES2 in the latest version

Comment: @Z.E. Sorry it's gone. But I just answered a similar question recently. Does this work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71063350/unity-build-not-working-on-android-12-due-to-write-permissions#comment125624123_71063350

Comment: @shingo shingo I will try it. Do you mean to say in the latest version of Unity, if an API level of less than 30 is used it will use Open GLES2? I guess it may be true because when Kit Kat was new Open GLES2 was popular

Comment: No, your problem may not be a graphic issue. Which API level are you using now?

Comment: It looks like ES2 was removed in Unity 2021, if your tablet doesn't support ES3, you may build your game with Unity 2020.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out using Shingo's comments.
My tablet only supports GL ES2 because
I ran CPU-Z to find that out.
I made a simple test program (just the default empty project with the blue sky)  with
unity 2020 (NOT the latest version) when GL ES 2 is selected.

Here is the gotcha-it looks like ES2 was removed in the latest version
of Unity 2021.2.10f-but it can be selected in the following way.
I started off by making my test program in unity 2020 save and closed the project. I selected GLES 2, as shown below,in this older version of unity (NOT using "Auto Graphic API")
[image]

Then I re-opened it, this makes unity convert the project so it
works in the latest version of unity 2021.2.10f-then I can see the GLES 2 (depreciated) appears in the
latest version of Unity. The GLES2 option circled in blue shown below

[image]

-GLES 2 support does not appear in the project if the project is not converted from the older version of unity.

Now I can use the latest version of unity to use with a tablet that supports
only GLES 2 by adding to the empty test program to eventually write my complete program.

I am happy I can still use my tablet with unity because:  it wasn't cheap to
buy and bought this year, if it works on this tablet it will work on a GLES3 tablet (because of backwards compatiability).