# Unity build not working on Android 12 due to write permissions

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-12

I have encountered an issue - a game built with Unity 2018.4.28f1 does not work on Android 12.
Tested it out on 7, 9, 10 and 11 - all work fine, but on Android 12 only a black screen is displayed after Unity logo and that's it.
Logs do not show any errors, not even warnings.
We do have more games (built with identical settings) and they are running just fine.

Setting Write Permissions: External (android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is added to Android Manifest file) allows to run the app for the first time.

If user blocks the permission, then next time the app runs again, asks for permissions.

If user grants the permissions, then app runs, but after closing and starting again black screen is displayed and app does not run.

Tried a lot of different things - changing blit type to always, changing Graphic APIs (both manual and automated), Target API level (Auto, 31, 32), API Compatibility (4.x and Standard), Enabling/disabling Multithreaded Rendering and Dynamic batching, 32-bit display buffer on/off.

Any suggestions what else shall I look at or how I can find out what is causing it?

Comment: Have you tried with a small API level (<30)?

Comment: @shingo man, you saved me :) Did not occur to me that building on lower versions than the device it self would fix it... Funny thing is that other games work fine with Target API Level set to Auto, whereas this one does not...

Comment: Doesn't lowering API level prevent your app to be installed on android 12?

Comment: No, it doesn't, it gets installed and runs without any issues on Android 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try building with lower version as suggested by  shingo in comments

Comment: As contributed by @shingo

Comment: Now Google does not accept apps with target sdk less than 31